# Bootstrap multi-line form-controls for a span

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having a problem displaying text when longer than one line in a span with a bootstrap form-control class (see images below). Looking for a solution in Bootstrap which would wrap the text in a box but keep the look even when overflowed on to the next line.

HTML Code
[image]

View Result
[image]

EDIT Complete Code:

```
@*Kpi Selection/Display*@
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">KPI Selection</label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
       <span id="KpiCode-display" class="form-control">
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WorkOrder.KpiDetails.DetailsKpi.KpiFull)
       </span>
       <span id="KpiSelection-edit" style="display: none">
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form-control` class needs to be applied to an input/select. The style it applies doesn't work with something like a span. If you're looking for a static text control, the class you should be applying is `form-control-static`. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static.

Comment: Used a text-area to semi-solve the problem until a better solution arises. Cheers Chris!

Comment: The _problem_ with this solution is that the text appears without a border that you should add manually. Moreover, it's something like add solid grey (#ced4da) border with border-radius .25rem. If you know scss, you could see how it is done in [_forms.scss file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_forms.scss) and default values in [_variables.scss file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/423e4a3811cc7278320d45129976f614f21df944/scss/_variables.scss).